# What is the purpose of "total" style in "hits" panel type in Kibana

Tags: kibana

Im new to Kibana and there is this doubt regarding it. I was trying the "hits" panel type with my query and then there was this "total" style in it. The other styles like the "bar" and "pie" returns understandable graphs,where as I cant figure what "total" is doing. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Total" displays the total hits for all the queries.

That is if we search for a query say "query 1" and we get say "n" hits, it will be shown as the number.

Now we clear the first one and we search for a second query, say "query 2" and it returns "m" number of hits.

Then if we use multiquery option and search for both "query 1" and "query 2" the total style would show "m+n" hits as the result.

To know more about the "total" style you can refer

[here](http://blog.qbox.io/advanced-kibana-analytics)

The following screenshots will be helpful for you to understand the "total" style in hits analytics

Suppose my first query is "spiderman"

[image]

You can see the the hits to be 24700

Next I type in a second query "ironman"

[image]

You can see the hits to be 2864 here.

And now we type in both queries using the multi-query option, which returns the following results:

[image]

Here you can see that the total hits to be 27564, which happens to be the sum of individual hits (24700+2864).